# How to replace Netflix icon?

Tags: icons

I have a nice icon for Netflix in the correct format for Windows (Netflix.ico).  How do I use it. If I tell Windows to change icon, it shows a bunch of icons in The current icon seems to be in %SystemRoot%\system32\Shell32.dll.  That is a file, not a folder.  How do I get my nice icon in there?

Answer (score 4):

You can also browse in other folders, not just in this "folder".

Simply click <kbd>Browse</kbd> at the dialog and search for your `Netflix.ico`-file.

[image]

Comment: Thanks.  That was quick.  I feel stupid but somehow happy.  Heritage972

Comment: You don't have to. Glad that I was able to help. If you would accept my answer, so that other users also can found the right solution faster, that would be nice. To do that, just click on the tick(✓).

Answer (score 0):

Just to be that guy, it IS possible to edit shell32.dll and insert your desired .ico. I am basing my guide on [this](http://www.sevenforums.com/tutorials/73191-icons-change-using-resource-hacker.html) page.

1. Download [IcoFX](http://icofx.ro/downloads.html) and install.
2. Go to shell32.dll (`C:\Windows\system32\shell32.dll` and right click it and select Properties.
3. Select the Security tab and then `Advanced`. We need to change the owner to administrators so that we can edit the permissions.
4. So, in `Advanced` click into the `Owner` tab and then hit edit. Select `Administrators` and Apply out of that window. You should now be back at the security tab.
5. Click onto administrator (or your user) and add the modify permission (`read` and `read and execute` should already be checked, but make sure they are checked
6. Now we have the permission to make changes to this file.
7. Open IcoFX and select from the menu `Tool -> Icon Resource Editor` then select the folder icon to open a .dll file.

   - Note that it will probably  default to a program directory, you'll need to navigate to `C:\Windows\System32\` and then you can select shell32.dll
8. Once opened, hit the page with a asterisk in it to add a icon entry. Notice the number, It'll make it easier to find later.
9. Hit close and it will prompt you to save. Save and try to select an icon again. You'll find you Netflix ico right off the bat.

---

Just a couple notes, you can easily make your OWN .dll with icons instead of messing with the system .dlls. Shouldn't matter, but what if some poor program tried to write to a certain entry and you already had it. Just make a copy of an existing .dll with icons. open the cop, remove all the old ones (one like shell32 has alot but wmp.dll just has a few for example) add your own, and save your copy. then you can rename it whatever you like.

Also, if you are looking for more options, it's worth looking at `imageres.dll` in system32 for a lot more options than `shell32.dll`

Answer (score -1):

Click the `Browse...` button and select your `Netflix.ico`.